Kotlin Multiplatform and Room: Cannot find implementation for model.database.AppDatabase
I'm making an app with Kotlin Multiplatform. I encountered an error when implementing the Room database, using this tutorial.
The error goes like this (Note that this error appears while debugging on both iOS and Android):

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myApp/com.example.myApp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for model.database.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist. Is Room annotation processor correctly configured?

I tried solving it with this Stackoverflow answer by following this recommendation:

This is a workaround, but you can build it with the following code.
https://github.com/cvivek07/KMM-PicSplash/blob/main/composeApp/build.gradle.kts
https://github.com/cvivek07/KMM-PicSplash/blob/main/composeApp/src/commonMain/kotlin/database/AppDatabase.kt

I implemented these lines:
In Gradle build (I think this is the only important workaround, am I right?)
dependencies {
//Replace it with ->  ksp(libs.room.compiler) when it is stable
add("kspCommonMainMetadata", libs.room.compiler)
}

tasks.withType<KotlinJvmCompile>().configureEach {
    if (name != "kspCommonMainKotlinMetadata" ) {
        dependsOn("kspCommonMainKotlinMetadata")
    }
}

And in the Database class:
abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase() ,DB {

    abstract fun ExampleDao(): ExampleDao

    override fun clearAllTables() {
        super.clearAllTables()
    }

}

// FIXME: Added a hack to resolve below issue:
// Class 'AppDatabase_Impl' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member 'clearAllTables'.
interface DB {
    fun clearAllTables() {}
}

But the error persists.

I was getting a similar error when running an example for JVM. The error is gone after adding "kspJvm," as shown below.
dependencies {
    listOf(
        "kspAndroid",
        "kspJvm",
        "kspIosSimulatorArm64",
        "kspIosX64",
        "kspIosArm64",
        "kspCommonMainMetadata",
    ).forEach {
        add(it, libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    }
}

